# C++ Compiler Complaining About Redefined Struct

Tags: c++, file, class, struct

I have some code. The code has four files. One file is the main file and the other three all all structures (namely, the "game" structure, the "player" structure, and the "scene" structure). In the game structure, I try to make an array of "scene" structures. The compiler complains in saying "redefinition of struct 'scene'". Any help?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

#### First suggestion

Make sure you include header guards in each header to prevent re-inclusion:

```
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GAME_H_INCLUDED

...whatever was in game.h before...

#endif /* GAME_H_INCLUDED */
```

Similarly for each of the other headers.

It is likely that one of your headers includes one of the others, and this is leading to the redefinition problem - because the header guards are missing.

Some compilers support a `#pragma once` to ensure that it only includes a given header once.  If all the compilers you will ever use support it, you can use the pragma instead of the portable and reliable mechanism shown; however, you do so at your own risk.

---

#### Second suggestion

No headers - that's puzzling (actually, 'worrying' is probably a better term for it).  How do the different files know about the different structures?

> In the game structure, I try to make an array of "scene" structures. The compiler complains in saying "redefinition of struct 'scene'".

It sounds as if you must be doing something like:

```
struct game
{
    ...
    struct scene { ... } *next_scene;
    struct scene { ... }  list_scenes[24];
    ...
};
```

This is not allowed; once you defined the structure tag once, you can't redefine it.  The minimum revision is:

```
struct game
{
    ...
    struct scene { ... } *next_scene;
    struct scene          list_scenes[24];
    ...
};
```

The recommended revision (with a lot of caveats still associated with your organization):

```
struct game
{
    ...
    struct scene { ... };
    struct scene *next_scene;
    struct scene  list_scenes[24];
    ...
};
```

But this stuff really, really belongs in a header if more than one source file is going to use the same structure; otherwise you're violating two canons of the Agile Development credo (although actually they're general purpose 'Good Programming' rules):

- DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself
- SPOT: Single Point of Truth

If more than one of your source files contains a definition of `struct game` (or `struct scene`, or `struct player`), then you are repeating yourself (bad, especially when you have to change the definition, and there is no long a single place to look for the definition of `struct game` (or `struct scene`, or `struct player`).

Header files are key to controlling the complexity of C++ development.

---

#### If the problem persists

If this still hasn't identified your problem, then it is going to be hard to guess what you've done.  You need to show the minimum code that shows the problem.  Take a copy of whichever file is failing, and call the new file `minimal.cpp` (or any new name, with the appropriate file suffix). Now edit `minimal.cpp`. Ruthlessly toss out everything after the error except what is needed to complete the namespaces or structures syntactically.  You can do that with strategically placed `#if 0` and `#endif` pairs, or with full-scale deletes.  After each change, save the file, check that you still get the same compilation error.  If you commented out the code with `#if 0 / #endif`, then after the compilation fails, delete that block of code (and save again, and check the compilation again).  The trailing material is usually trivial to deal with; you need only a few appropriately placed close braces and semi-colons.

After that, you start eliminating material before the error.  Keep going until there isn't a line of your code that you can remove without losing the error during compilation.

At that point, if the test case is under 40 lines, you have something you can put into your question.  Until then, you've not done a good enough job. (Note that you don't need any comments in the repro; it will be simple enough to understand without any.)

This how you track down any troublesome bug - eliminate as much code as possible as quickly as possible, leaving you with just the troublesome stuff.

Comment: My project doesn't have any header files.

Comment: @Monkeyanator - Then you have a bizarrely organized project. Edit the question and show how your code/files are organized.

Comment: I have a file named gamestruct.cpp and just created gamestruct.h

Comment: but when i include gamestruct.h in the main file it doesn't recognize the structure game

Comment: We need to see your code; working blind is - well, hard.  It is difficult for us to guess what mistake you are making that is 'not what we do' after coding in C++ for a few years.  So, make the minimal code to reproduce the problem and add it to your question. (For example, the `struct game` in `gamestruct.h` should have a single member, probably an `int` or some other built-in type, so you need no other headers to make it compile; gamestruct.h will be three lines total, or 6 if you include header guards as you should, though they are not critical for the repro).

Comment: struct gamePlayer cPlayer; //IT SAYS THIS HAS INCOMPLETE TYPE

Comment: If you've not already defined the 'struct gamePlayer' type, then it is is correct.